# Calendar eTags Mismatch error - Precautions taken, still getting error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets

I am creating a Google Apps Spreadsheet roster for my workplace. the actual roster is fairly simple, with a few calculations and an onEdit script that changes the cell colour, depending on duty for that hour.

One major part of this new roster is the ability to create Google calendar events for each person to notify them of the shifts. The roster is created and events should be created monthly. At the beginning of the month, the staff member doing the roster, will run a function, and create all events for that month, for each person. (I hope that made sense...)

My code is listed below. The sheet called "Splash" (Sheet index 0) contains the Name and Email of each Staff member on the team. The rosters will be created on sheet index 1 through infinity.

On the Roster sheet itself, column A contains the name of each Staff. Column B contains the Start time and C contains the End time.

```
function sendInvites() {
  // Gather Prelim Information
  var splash = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Splash");
  var nameRange = splash.getRange("A6:B9"); // Need to change this to be the full staff list in Splash

  var inviteSheet = Browser.inputBox("Sheet to send invites from (Number)", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL)
  var days = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[inviteSheet];
  var dayRange;

  //Initiate iteration through Names, according to the Splash sheet
  for(nameRow=nameRange.getRow(); nameRow<=9; nameRow++){ //Change to Corresponding iterate
    // Gather Name and Email information for the each person
    var col = nameRange.getColumn();
    var row = nameRow;
    var name = splash.getRange(row, col).getValue();
    var email = splash.getRange(row, col+1).getValue();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email);

    //Initiate iteration through Days, according to the Roster
    for(i=0; i<=6; i++){
      //Specify Day Ranges
      switch(i){
        case 0: //Saturday
          dayRange = days.getRange("A1:O6"); break;
        case 1: //Sunday
          dayRange = days.getRange("A10:O15"); break;
        case 2: //Monday
          dayRange = days.getRange("A19:O41"); break;
        case 3: //Tuesday
          dayRange = days.getRange("A45:O67"); break;
        case 4: //Wednesday
          dayRange = days.getRange("A71:O93"); break;
        case 5: //Thursday
          dayRange = days.getRange("A97:O119"); break;
        case 6: //Friday
          dayRange = days.getRange("A123:O145"); break;
      }

      //Find Name in dayRange
      for(dayRow=dayRange.getRow(); dayRow<=dayRange.getLastRow(); dayRow++){
        var searchCol = dayRange.getColumn();
        var searchRow = dayRow;        
        var searchName = days.getRange(searchRow, searchCol).getValue();

        if (name==searchName){
          // Gather and format Date and Time information for invitation
          var eventName = "Phones";
          var date = Utilities.formatDate(dayRange.getValue(), "GMT+1000", "EEE MMM dd yyyy");
          var startCell = days.getRange(searchRow, searchCol+1).getValue();
          var endCell = days.getRange(searchRow, searchCol+2).getValue();

          if (startCell != ""){
            var startTime = date + " " + Utilities.formatDate(startCell, "GMT+1000", "HH:mm:ss");
            var endTime = date + " " + Utilities.formatDate(endCell, "GMT+1000", "HH:mm:ss");

            //Create a calendar event with the details above
            Utilities.sleep(500); //Pause event creation for half second, to allow the last event to be fully created (Avoids "Calendar: Mismatch: etags error")
            cal.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime)).removeAllReminders();
          }

          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having right now is that the logic works, but not all the events are being created. I am testing with four staff, including myself. it will only complete one and a half iterations of Names before throwing a Calendar: Mismatch: etags error.

I am aware that this error occurs when a Calendar is being changed twice, at one time. I added a sleep time of half a second, before event creation, to allow for this. It is much rarer now, but still occurring. I have tried making it a 2 second sleep, I have tried moving it to different points. All of this will still eventuate with the eTags error.

Not too sure where to go from here. I feel like the roster is almost ready to be used, but it's just not stable enough yet.

Let me know if you have any ideas, or if you need some clarification.

Comment: Try the most recent workaround suggested in Issue 264 http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=264#c67

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. I've been keeping a track of Issue 264, but had not seen that post. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a try/catch to avoid "etags" errors. The operation generating the error is removeAllReminders() as it takes some time to create a new contact object in Google's distributed storage.

I use a helper function to avoid these dreaded "etags" errors:

```
function retryMethod(object, method) {
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    try {
      return object[method]();
    }
    catch (e) {
      if (e.message.indexOf('Mismatch: etags') == -1) throw e;
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
  throw new Error('retryMethod failed after retrys method ', method, ' object ', object)
}
```

You could then rewrite your "cal.createEvent(" line into:

```
retryMethod(cal.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime)), 'removeAllReminders');
```

Remember to check if the createEvent is null.

Actually my current helper function is slightly different as most of the function calls raising "etags" errors are in fact successful.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking about using a try/catch, but it is a kind of messy solution... Looks like the Issue 264 workaround is working for the time being. If that still causes issues, I'll pop in a try/catch  :)